Vector space of homogeneous polynomials
I saw this question here: Dimension of a vector space of polynomials in 3 variables of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{R}$
So, "Let $V$ be a vector space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ in 3 variables over $\mathbb{R}$". But how this forms a vector space? Because if it doesn't contain $0$.

A polynomial with all zero coefficients is still a polynomial.

@paulina yes but $0$ don't have degree $d$.

The space of all homogenous polynomials is definitely not a vector space (as the comments on the other question indicate.) The set of homogenous polynomials of fixed degree $d$ would technically be not a vector space, as you say, but in context I would expect that "the vector space of homogenous polynomials in three variables of degree $d$" would mean the homogenous polynomials in three variables of degree $d$ together with $0$, which is a vector space.

@JairTaylor so $0$ is not a polynomial of degree $d$ but I need to add it to the set to form a vector space, is correct?

Yes, if $0$ is not added it wouldn't be a vector space so if that's not what is intended by that phrase then it would be incorrect.

In the context of graded rings, $0$ has every degree.
Namely, let $R = \sum_n R_n$ be a graded ring. The elements of $R_n$ are called homogeneous of degree $n$. Recall that $0 \in R_n$ is always true, by definition, so in this sense $0$ is homogeneous of degree $n$ for every $n$.
In our case, $R = \mathbb{R}[x,y,z] = \sum_n \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_n$ where $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_n$ consists of those polynomials $\sum_{i,j,k} a_{i,j,k} x^i y^j z^k$ such that $a_{i,j,k} \neq 0 \implies i+j+k=n$. Equivalently, $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_n$ is the subspace generated by the $x^i y^j z^k$ with $i+j+k=n$. In particular, again, $0 \in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_n$, and it is a vector space.
